# How to rollback to R 2.12.1 version on Ubuntu?

Tags: r, ubuntu

I was using R 2.12.1 on my desktop and recently the R got updated to the new version R 2.13.0 which is not I want. Is there anyway to use the R 2.12.1 again and how can I use that?

Comment: what problems did the latest version cause you?

Comment: some of the bioconductor libraries which I am using are not supported in latest version of R, so I really want to use the old R version.

Comment: I would ask on `r-sig-debian`.

Comment: this question is off topic on the site, but you might find this info interesting : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticHowto Look for "Force version" in the package menu of the package manager.

Comment: To Joris' point, this may be a better question for http://askubuntu.com another stack exchange site, officially supported by the ubuntu community.

Answer (score 2):

[packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/r-base) seems to have R 2.11.2 for maverick, so that is no help.  You may try to see if the [Michael's PPA site on launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~marutter/+archive/rrutter) has a rollback feature so that you can get that version there. (Edit: Doesn't seem so. Hmpf.)

Barring that, I would grab the Debian source for 2.12.2 (using the [snapshot.debian.org](http://snapshot.debian.org) site which has [**all previous Debian version of r-base**](http://snapshot.debian.org/package/r-base/) and build replacement `.deb` binaries from that.

Or ... can't you upgrade BioC to a version that works with R 2.13.0?  Didn't BioC just have a release too?

Lastly, by far the easiest is to

- uncomment the entry for CRAN in `/etc/apt/sources.list`
- update, and
- install the most recent Ubuntu version, which is 2.11.2 as shown above.

Ubuntu's next release will get presumably 2.12.* too, so you could also try upgrading to Ubuntu 11.4 now (but note that it is not yet released).

Comment: I noticed that too. I wonder if he can just use the debian package on CRAN?

Comment: Please no, do not mix Debian and Ubuntu unless you **really** know what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

If it was a recent update, it's likely still on your system:

```
/var/cache/apt/archives
```

Comment: but what exactly I need do for using the older version?

Comment: /var/cache/apt/archives is empty

Comment: Shitty. Well there's two options. Search the net for a package of the version you're looking for. Or manually download the pieces from http://www.r-project.org (CRAN Mirror) and install using the instruction from here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware . You shouldn't have any problems with a debian package either, you'll probably find one under debian/etch-.../